# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

i'm new to zookeeper and started to run zookeeper and got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: zoo1
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:848)
```

my zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/st/storm/datadir/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2 
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

my /etc/hosts is

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters 
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your zoo.cfg you have the following lines

```
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3 need to be replaced with actual IP addresses. Such as,

```
server.1=192.168.1.100:2888:3888 
server.2=192.168.1.101:2888:3888 
server.3=192.168.1.102:2888:3888
```

Or whatever the actual IP addresses that your zookeeper nodes are located at.

**EDIT**

If you only have zookeeper running on one machine and therefore one ip address. You would change the config to be something similar.

```
server.1=192.168.1.100:2888:3888
```

Since you only have one ip address you only need one entry in configuration. The number of zookeeper nodes you have is up to you to decide, 3 isn't a magic number. Though the more machines you you'll have more redundancy.

Comment: but sorry for my question that , i have one ip address , how can i got three ip address

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. Stackoverflow is mostly used for specific questions about specific problems. Like this question. If you have a specific Storm question you should post a new question and tag it with Apache Storm. I hope that helps.

Comment: really thanks for your help , i asked that because i'm now want to submit a topology in production cluster so is zookeeper will in production mode or not ?

Comment: It's advised to have 3+ nodes in a Zookeeper instances in production to protect against failures. But that usually requires 3+ machines. But it really just depends on your needs. I don't really know the specifics of your situation enough to be able to answer that.

Comment: You're welcome, if you felt I answered your question a upvote and/or accepted answer is appreciated. You might have already done this.